# Is $f: A\to A$ surjective?

Tags: functions

I'm new to this subject, and having difficulties to understand this

Let $A$ be $\left]1,\infty\right[.$ Is image $f\colon A\to A,$ $f(x)=\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}$ surjective?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `:` instead of `\colon` for $:$ for function mappings.

Comment: This question is asking the following: given $1 < y < \infty$, can you solve $y = \dfrac{x+1}{x-1}$ for $y$ in terms of $x$ (and $x$ still satisfy $1 < x < \infty$).

Comment: Err whoops. Solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's surjective then for any $k \in A= (1,\infty)$ there should be an $x \in A= (1,\infty)$ so that $\frac{x+1}{x-1} = k$.  So we should attempt to solve for $x$ in terms of $k$.  If we can solve and show there is always a solution that will prove that $f$ is surjective.  If we find a "loophole" and a counter example of $k$ that doesn't have a solution it is not.

So $\frac{x+1}{x-1} = k$

$x + 1 = k(x-1) = kx -k$

$kx-x = k+1$

$x(k-1) = k+1$.  If we assume $k-1 \ne 0$ we can divide by $k-1$.  And we *can* assume $k \in A$ so $k > 1$ so $k - 1> 0$.

So $x = \frac {k+1}{k-1}$.

SO does that mean $f$ is surjective?  Well, it will *IF* we know that $x=\frac {k+1}{k-1} \in A$.

$k > 1$ so $k -1 > 0$.  And $k+1 > k > k-1 > 0$ so $\frac {k+1}{k-1} > 1$ so $x = \frac {k+1}{k-1} \in A$.

So... recap.

For any $k \in A$ then.... 1) $x=\frac {k+1}{k-1} \in A$ and $f(x) = \frac {\frac {k+1}{k-1} + 1}{\frac {k+1}{k-1} -1}=$

$\frac {\frac {k+1}{k-1} + 1}{\frac {k+1}{k-1} -1}\frac {k-1}{k-1} = \frac {(k+1)+(k-1)}{(k+1)- (k-1)}=$

$\frac {2k}{2} = k$.

So for every $k \in A$ there *does* exist an $x \in A$ (namely $x = \frac{k+1}{k-1}$ so that $f(x) = k$.  And hence, $f$ is, by definition, surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. $\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$. So given any $y\in (1,\infty)$, there exists $0<x_0,x_1<\infty$ such that $f(x_0)<y<f(x_1)$ since $f$ is continuous on $(1,\infty)$, we can conclude by the intermediate value theorem that there exists some $c\in (x_0,x_1)\subset (1,\infty)$ such that $f(c)=y$.

It only makes sense to say that $f(\infty)=1$ and $f(1)=\infty$ if you define $f$ this way.

Answer (score 1):

$y= 1+\dfrac{2}{x-1}$; $x \in (1,\infty)$.

$y-1=\dfrac{2}{x-1}$; $(x-1) \in (0,\infty)$;

We get taking limits

$x \rightarrow 1^+$, and $x \rightarrow \infty$, with the continuity of $(y-1)$, and the IVT :

Image $=${$y-1$}$ = (0,\infty)$;

The corresponding $(x-1)$:

$x-1=\dfrac{2}{y-1}$; $(y-1) \in (0,\infty)$;

In essence we are looking at a hyperbola

$YX=2$ in the first quadrant, symmetric about $Y=X$.

What does the symmetry imply?

Comment: I think you also once you have $YX=2$ you could argue using the fact that inverses in $\Bbb R$ exist and are unique

Comment: J.W.Tanner. Nice, broader than what I had in mind: $f=f^{-1}$.Thanks.